# Zsh startup error, after brew update

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh

I recently ran a `brew update`, and have been having the following error when I start up an iTerm2 shell:

[image]

I have tried basically everything I've googled, including `brew install gdbm,  brew unlink gdbm && brew link gdbm`, and `for x in $(brew list -1); do brew unlink $x; brew link $x; done`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to this removal of the symlink.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/c16e7a1dfa75e9891d017702a1d67f4420f1ae81

If you reinstall zsh using `brew reinstall zsh`, it will recompile zsh using the latest GDBM library.